# What is difference between ArrayNode and JsonNode in FasterXMl Jackson Api?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

I have one case in which data (Json Array Data) will be fetched from cache and then using java8 stream it need to be filter out so I may need to use ArrayNode or JsonNode but dont have idea about use cases of both. If any one can give example how can I read json data using JSONNode or Arraynode from json file and how can I use stream to filter those JsonNode or ArrayNode.

Comment: The difference is same as that of `Object` and `array of Objects`. `JsonNode` is object of JSON and `ArrayNode` is array of `JsonNode` object.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare yes but suppose if I parse a json file which have arrays of json data , then holder should be arraynode right ? but I can even make object of jsonnode to hold that json arrays of data.

Comment: `JsonNode`- abstract superclass for any Jackson node.
`ArrayNode` - extends JsonNode and used to represent array in json [].
`ObjectNode` - extends JsonNode and used to represent object in json {}.[JsonNode Hierarchy diagram with ArrayNode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P32nb.png) So `JsonNode` and `ArrayNode` have basically the same api. You dont even need to cast JsonNode to ArrayNode, just check  `if(jsonNode.isArray()){}` both of them have `forEach` streaming api, but you can use `StreamSupport.stream(node.spliterator(), false).filter(val-> /*some filter code here...*/);`

Comment: @RahulRabhadiya Yes, you can make an array of `JsonNode`. But Jackson is providing us this datatype with its methods, then why we bother about to create an array of JsonNode and handling to conversions(to/from Json). Instead use `ArrayNode` directly.